# Java: Regex matching in an unexpected situation

Tags: java, regex, servlets

I'm working on a servlet that effectively routes to other servlets, performing some nifty helper functions along the way. My web.xml is configured to direct all traffic through this class, and the class routes the requests based on pathInfo and regex logic. My code looks like this:

```
public class API1 extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();

        if (pathInfo.matches("/.*/.*/.*/?")) {
            _fooBarBazHandler.get(req, resp);
        } else if (pathInfo.matches("/.*/.*/?")) {
            _fooBarHandler.get(req, resp);
        } else if (pathInfo.matches("/.*/?")) {
            _fooHandler.get(req, resp);
        } else {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }
    }
...
}
```

Now, the idea is that if I hit `http://host/FooService/foo/bar/baz` that it would redirect to the `_fooBarBazHandler`, `http://host/FooService/foo/bar` would hit the `_fooBarHandler`, and `http://host/FooService/foo` would hit the `_fooHandler`

For some reason, however, `http://host/FooService/foo` is apparently matching on `_fooBarHandler`. To be absolutely clear, using the debugger, I've ascertained that the value of `pathInfo` is "/foo".

My regex isn't too strong. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want stronger regexp, replace every `.` with `[^/]` to not match slashes.

Comment: ...or use reluctant quantifiers. `.*` -> `.*?`, that way you won't match slashes. Also, `.*` is not a good idea - what about `http://host/FooService///foo` ? Use `.+?` instead.

Comment: Even with reluctant quantifiers, the first regexp would match `/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/`, which probably is not intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the regexp `/.*/.*/?` will *not* match `"/foo"`.  your bug is elsewhere (sorry!).

see http://fiddle.re/0g28 (click on blue "Java")

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what happened. I sat back down to the problem, and it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have performed the test in my machine and the third test is the one that returns true - so I agree with Andrew Cooke - the bug is elsewhere.